# How Database Migration is possible in Windows Azure?

Tags: c#, azure, relational-database

How to migrate database from sql azure to another DB server such as oracle for a single application hosted in windows azure for one client sql azure and for another client oracle as DB Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very clear,  but in most cases you can use [the SQL Azure Migration Wizard](http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/) when you want to migrate to and from the cloud.

> The SQL Azure Migration Wizard (SQLAzureMW) gives you the options to
>   analyzes, generates scripts, and migrate data (via BCP) from:
>
> - SQL Server to SQL Azure
> - SQL Azure to SQL Server
> - SQL Azure to SQL Azure

Answer (score 0):

As Sandrino mentions, question not clear, you could always use a BACPAC export to blob storage.

How to: Export a Data-tier Application (SQL Azure):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh335292.aspx

I prefer this option over the Migration Wizard, but have to say its a great tool!

*Note the SQL Database Migration Wizard is not supported, still an excellent tool and never failed me :)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee730904.aspx